# I have an array in a json and when I try to access it with the following code it has an error for multiple words. Can anybody help fix the code

Tags: discord.js

The error code it shows is:

```
                   msg.channel.send(spell.spelldictionary[i][1])
                                                             ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

The index code is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const token = '';
const PREFIX = '%';
const spell = require('./spells.json')
bot.on('message', msg =>{
  if(!msg.author.bot && msg.content.startsWith(PREFIX))
      {
          let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
          switch(args[0])
          {
              case 'D&D':
                  switch(args[1])
                  {
                      case 'spellinfo':
                          let spellname = args.slice(2);
                          for(i = 0; i < spell.spelldictionary.length; i++)
                          {
                              if(spellname == spell.spelldictionary[i][0])
                              {
                                  break;
                              }
                          }
                          msg.channel.send(spell.spelldictionary[i][1])
                      break;
                  }
              break;
          }
      }
}
bot.login(token)
```

and the JSON file is the following:

```
{
    "spelldictionary": [
        ["Acid Splash","a"],
        ["Aid","a"],
        ["Alarm","a"],
        ["Alter Self","a"],
        ["Animal Friendship","a"],
        ["Animal Messenger","a"],
        ["Animal Shapes","a"],
        ["Animate Dead","a"],
        ["Animate Objects","a"],
        ["Antilife Shell","a"],
        ["Antimagic Field","a"],
        ["Antipathy","a"],
        ["Arcane Eye","a"],
        ["Arcane Gate","a"],
        ["Arcane Lock","a"],
        ["Armour of Agathys","a"],
        ["Arms of Hadar","a"],
        ["Astral Projection","a"],
        ["Augury","a"],
        ["Aura of Life","a"],
        ["Aura of Purity","a"],
        ["Aura of Vitality","a"],
        ["Awaken","a"],
        ["Bane","a"]
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, however I don't understand much JavaScript as I am a beginner so can you try not to make answers too complicated.

Comment: It appears that `spellDictionary` is either not a two dimensional array, or the second dimension has less than two elements.

Comment: In short, you're apparently not reading the JSON correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `spellname` is not in `spell.spelldictionary`, `i` becomes `spell.spelldictionary.length` after the for loop, and the execution of `msg.channel.send(spell.spelldictionary[i][1])` causes the error.

You can avoid it by moving `msg.channel.send` before `break` in the for loop, so that no message will be sent in this case. Also, it is better to explicitly declare `i` before using it, or it may cause some unexpected bugs after your code becomes more complicate.

```js
let spellname = args.slice(2);
for(let i = 0; i < spell.spelldictionary.length; i++) // <<
{
    if(spellname == spell.spelldictionary[i][0])
    {
        msg.channel.send(spell.spelldictionary[i][1]); // <<
        break;
    }
}
// do nothing here
```

#### Advanced solution

To prevent this kind of error, you can try to use some [methods of Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Instance_methods). In this case, you may want to use [array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).
It returns the first element that satisfies the test function, or `undefined` if no such element exists.

In your case, the test function is `elm => elm[0]==spell`, so you can rewrite it to:

```js
// `elm` is the same as `spell.spelldictionary[i]` in your code
const elm = spell.spelldictionary.find(elm => spellname==elm[0]);
if (elm !== undefined) { // if found
    msg.channel.send(elm[1]);
}
```